# how to find data in array of object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, node-modules

I find in array of object and match _id and is_active both key

ex

```
 {
    _id:'12333333333333'
    name:'test',
    array:[{
        id:'1233449',
        is_active:true
    },{
        id:'7987979',
        is_active:false
    },{
        id:'9558555',
        is_active:true
    },{
        id:'2564654',
        is_active:false
    }]
 }
```

find data using mongo query

```
db.getCollection('demo').find({'array.id':'7987979','array.is_active':false});
```

not working

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isnt working for you is because you are running a find operation on the array directly.

When querying for things within an array you can use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to obtain an **entire document** that contains the matching array element.

If you need a custom output you can use Aggregation, with the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation in the pipeline on the array field.

Try this out on your collection and understand what it is doing

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([{
        $unwind:"$array"
    },{
        $match:{
            $and:[
                {"array.id":'your_id'},
                {"array.is_active":boolean}
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: but we need to find operation bcuz we are creating virtual populate so not possible in aggregate